# Comparing XML side-by-side

Tags: xml, compare

I need to compare two xml files and then show a screen like the one in WinMerge (both files and the differences reded and greened). It is well know as side-by-side comparation. 
Is there any tool to do that? 
and last but not lease, an open source toool?

Comment: You are looking for what is generally known as a diff viewer. I don't know an open source viewer for Windows offhand, but hopefully that will find you something.

Answer (score 1):

You question does not really show that you even researched what you are looking for because with one search of google I found a tool that does what you are looking for it is called Altova.

Link - [This is the tool I found it's not open source but it has the red and green feature you are looking for.](http://www.altova.com/diffdog/xml-diff.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more tool WinMerge which is able to compare directories, and files. It is free and userfriendly, you can download it from http://winmerge.org/.